# Setting font-family to sans-serif causes jQuery to calculate incorrect outerWidth

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, firefox, width

Somehow, merely setting a `font-family: sans-serif` style in the following document is causing `li` tag contents to wrap in IE 11.0.9600.16438 and FireFox 25.0.1 but not in Chrome 31.0.1650.57. I first noticed it when I noticed that some `li` tags were wrapping unnecessarily while using SimpleModal 1.4.4. I managed to reproduce this by adding, piece-by-piece, markup and CSS styles to a standalone document. Finally, I used jQuery's `outerWidth` and `outerHeight` methods to retrieve a calculated size, which I've confirmed is just what SimpleModal uses.

**EDIT**: Just to be clear, I am using the `outerWidth` and `outerHeight` results to set an explicit size on the modal dialog. This is what SimpleModal does and it's apparently crucial to the proper functioning of dialogs. My question is in the context of SimpleModal but I've narrowed down the strange behavior to jQuery.

Here's the markup *without* `font-family: sans-serif`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            * { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-family: sans-serif; }
            ul { margin: 0 0 0.5rem; padding: 0 0 0 2rem; list-style: disc; }
            p { margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0; padding: 0 }
            .simplemodal-wrap { height: 100%; outline: 0; width: 100%; overflow: visible; }
            .simplemodal-data { background-color: #ddd; padding: 1rem; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="simplemodal-container" style="position: fixed; left: 25px; top: 75px; z-index: 1002;">
                <div class="simplemodal-wrap">
                    <div class="simplemodal-data">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum:</p><ul><li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li><li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li><li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li><li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </li><li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li><li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </li></ul><p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum :</p><ul><li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </li><li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </li></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var sc = $(".simplemodal-container");
                var outerWidth = sc.outerWidth(true);
                var outerHeight = sc.outerHeight(true);

                $("main").append("<div>outerWidth(true) x outerHeight(true):<br>" + outerWidth + " x " + outerHeight + "</div>");

                sc.css({ width: outerWidth, height: outerHeight });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The results in all three browsers look correct (here's Chrome as an example):

[image: Chrome]

Now, simply add `font-family: sans-serif;` to the `*` selector and refresh all three browsers. Suddenly, the width calculation is wrong!

[image: IE 11]
[image: FireFox 25.0.1]

Increasing the width by **one pixel** in IE and FireFox causes the `li` tags to no longer wrap.

What's going on here? Is this some kind of rounding bug with font size calculations?

**EDIT**: Here's the code I ended up adding to jquery.simplemodal-1.4.4.js on line 553:

```
// jQuery truncates subpixel width and height calculations
// Fixed incorrect wrapping in Mozilla
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (userAgent.length >= 7 && userAgent.substring(0, 7) === "mozilla") {
    dw++;
    dh++;
}
```

Such a hack, but a necessarily one, apparently. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on is that jQuery's `outerWidth` API is broken by design: it returns an integer number of CSS pixels.

In a browser that does subpixel text shaping and positioning (which Firefox and IE do and Chrome does not), the width of a string of text is not going to be an integer number of CSS pixels, in general.  And even in Chrome, if you have a high-DPI screen, so that one CSS pixel corresponds to two or more device pixels, the width of a string of text can end up being a non-integral number of CSS pixels.

What jQuery then does is effectively take the actual width and round down to an integer.  Which means the number you get is too small if the text wasn't exactly an integer number of pixels wide.

What you probably want to do is use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the actual dimensions of the box without rounding.  And complain to the jQuery authors about jQuery not providing a convenient API for that.  ;)

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I filed a bug that can be viewed at http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14556. I also mentioned this thread. This seems like a pretty clear-cut bug to me. I hope I get a good response from them.

Comment: Unfortunately, the broken code is within SimpleModal's library. I generally try to avoid modifying library code directly but it seems in this case that the SimpleModal project isn't getting its author's attention much these days.

Comment: @NathanAldenSr Glad to help.  Library bugs are the worst.  :(

Comment: Unfortunately, `getBoundingClientRect()` returns all 0s at the place where SimpleModal calculates the width and height. I think SimpleModal is relying on jQuery to do a custom calculation of what is (at that place in the framework code) an element whose width and height are *actually* `auto`.

Comment: Hmm.  `getBoundingClientRect()` will do layout and return the actual values, in general.  I don't know why it's not working in your case....